# Cable management strategy for a small chassis switch

Tags: switch, cable, cable-management

I'm working with a small site buildout that contains a single HP ProCurve 4200vl chassis switch. The data cabling contractor did not provision for any cable management. I'm looking at the rack pictured below and would like some suggestions on how to cleanly patch down to the switch below *without* vertical managers. I wanted to avoid full vertical management since this setup will only utilize 40-50 cables. Is there a clean way to do this? Would something like the [NeatPatch](http://www.neatpatch.com/products.html) be the best approach? If the answer is *velcro*, I guess that works, too...

[image]

Comment: Neatpatch is aimed at being used with 1U switches rather than chassis switches. (As an aside, I find the little label that says "asa" on the Cisco ASA to be adorable!)

Comment: Doesn't that say '888' ?

Comment: @thinice My super-awesome ctrl+scrollwheel zooming skills show otherwise :) http://i.imgur.com/Uy4qv.png

Comment: It was a joke ;)  - I really want to move the WAP off of the top of the switch >.>

Comment: Oh, it's sitting there temporarily for configuration (close to the console cable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that a combination of [these](http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/horizontal-cable-management.asp#34-208000) and velcro may be your best bet.

Comment: It would also be quite helpful to add vertical cable management into the mix here.

Comment: @ErikA agreed, but the OP said that he wanted to avoid vertical.

Comment: Whoops - missed that. :)

Answer (score 4):

After taking a look at port counts and such, this was easily accomplished with velcro and 3-foot cables. Not too bad...

[image]